# Multiple JSON responses in a single Rails controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have my show method on a controller in my application and in the response block I have

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :layout =>'placing', :next_days => @next_days}# show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @artist }
  format.json { render :partial => "places/show.json", :artist => @artist } }
end
```

This, generates a json output based in the show.json partial in /places/1.json for example, but what if I want one more json output, like /places/alternative_1.json? How can I do that if there is already a json format block inside respond_to?

Any help is appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: This feels more like a routing question than a response question. How would you get to your other output? You indicate a path, but is that the only way? Are you going to be returning the same variable either way, so the same respond_to would work? Or is it a completely different set of logic that would return a different set of data?

Comment: Hello, it's the same data... the problem is: this current format.json will have to remain there, it renders a partial that contains a data in a specific format. I wanted another json response inside the same controller action but it doesn't seem possible. Anyway, the workaround is creating another action in the controller,  and routing it. Then it will be like /places/manage/1 for example.

Answer (score 0):

Then you will have to make some logic inside your `format.json` block changing what you are associating to `:partial` (currently is `"places/show.json"`), or create another route...

As `format.json { render ... }` is normal Ruby code, you could do something like:

```
format.json do 
  json_partial = json_for_this_case #example
  render :partial => json_partial, :locals => {:artist => @artist}
end
```